# The target execution of WebSphere Application Server v7.0 is not defined

Tags: apache-flex, websphere, flash-builder

[image]I'm using spring with flex (with IDE flash builder 4.6)

I have this error The target execution of WebSphere Application Server v7.0 is not defined. please where should I configure the server

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're running into a problem using FB's application server integration. I don't even remember FB supporting WebSphere.

It's getting hard to remember how this used to be done, but I know we never used to use this type of functionality in Flash Builder. It's possible to deploy your mid-tier app in Tomcat (or WAS), start that, and then run/debug your Flex app which connects to that independently started server.

Depending on how it connects (Blaze/Granite remoting, REST, etc) it may be harder or easier to do that, but the point is that I'm sure you don't need to use this functionality in FB.

If you still want to try using that functionality, I'm pretty sure the configuration is somewhere in that list on the left side of the dialog posted, but again I never bothered with it.